# Watson Dialog Auto Learn

Tags: ibm-watson

I have seen some references to the Auto-learn function of Watson Dialog but I can't find coverage in any of the documentation. Can you point me to a source of information on how best to use Auto-Learn?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank you for your feedback, we are always working to improve our documentation.
For your immediate benefit, auto-learn is a bit of a misleading name for a feature t, but the name has stuck.
Autolearn has become the "did you mean..." with four bullet points that shows when a user sends an input that has no direct matches.

A little history...at one time, we thought that if a user typed something, saw the did you mean... and clicked a link, their intial input must have meant the same thing as the one they clicked, the system should automatically remember that.

Imagine this:
"What are your credit card fees?"
Did you mean... 1. apply for a credit card 2. cancel a credit card 3. pay your bill
*click* apply for a credit card

The user was simply interested in that, but obviously the two DO NOT have the same meaning. So we realized thats a bad idea, the system will learn incorrectly. However, we still call it auto learn.

Comment: Just to add to this, if you are creating a process flow (where you drive the user through a process), you should switch off auto-learn for nodes in that process. Otherwise the user can potentially jump to middle of a process flow.